# How to make jqPlot stackedbar inherit colors from any page control (HTML, ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, jqplot

I have got jqPlot stacked bar chart on my ASP.NET page. Is it possible for each series of stacked bar to have specific color, which would be inherited/taken/read from any control on page (asp:TextBox, div, asp:Label, etc.) for example with help of javascript, jQuery, etc.?
How would you programmatically do it please?
Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Don't know if it work as 'simple' bar chart but if so you have the `varyBarColor` series option : `series: [{yaxis: renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer, rendererOptions: {varyBarColor: true}}]`. You can also specify your own colors array thanks to `seriesColors` option : `seriesColors: myColors` (If there are more series than colors, colors will wrap around and start at the beginning again.)

Comment: Thank you AnthonyLeGovic for your response, that has valuable content. I am sorry I was not more specific. I have got some ASP.NET controls on my page and I need each series of stacked bar to inherit  its colors. At the moment I am trying to accomplish that on ASP.NET controls data binding.